# Gparted enable more logging

Tags: disk, io, gparted, scsi

I cannot find a way for Gparted to produce more informative logs in the [manual](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual). What I am looking for is to find out why exactly did e cartain I/O operation fail (more details about the SCSI command that returned the error etc.). What I got so far and what is not enough is:

```
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdc
```

Comment: Failing storage? Is there anything in `dmesg`?

Comment: I/O errors are usually enough to know the drive is defective.